# Adobe Dreamweaver Install Problem

Tags: installation, dreamweaver

Attempting to install Dreamweaver via web download. Get Grey Box stating:

> QAdobe Dreamweaver CS4 - Setup Error
>
> Setup has encountered an error and cannot continue. Contact Adobe Customer Support for assistance.

This is the only text shown for the error. System is Windows XP 5.1 on 32 bit laptop.

Comment: not programming related, I'd suggest you contact Customer Support.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the [Windows Installer Cleanup Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301), then retry the setup.